# check the number of audio and video tracks with mkvmerge

Tags: bash, scripting

I have written this small script:

```
subliminal -l en  -- *.mp4
subliminal -l es  -- *.mp4

for i in *".mp4"; do
i=${i%.mp4} 
mkvmerge -o "$i.mkv" \
    --language 1:eng -a 1 -d 0 -S -T "$i.mp4" \
    --language 0:eng -s 0 -D -A -T "$i.en.srt" \
    --language 0:spa -s 0 -D -A -T "$i.es.srt" \
    --track-order 0:0,0:1,1:0,2:0
done
```

It downloads english and spanish subtitles using subliminal to a folder with .mp4 chapters from a TV show.
After that, mkvmerge will put together all these files (.mp4 and .srt's) in a .mkv file.

The problem is that sometimes the .mp4 file has not its audio track in position 1 (-a 1) nor its video track in position 0 (-d 0).

My question is how to implement cases in bash? For example, check the .mp4 file first and if the audio and video tracks are 1 and 0, respectively, do ...
but if the audio and video tracks are 0 and 1 do another thing.

Regards

Comment: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/bash-case-statement/

Comment: can you give an example, with mkvinfo for example, to show the problem of position